# How to setup a wireless proxy server (user need to login first before internet access)

Tags: wireless-networking, bandwidth, wireless-access-point, proxy-server

Could you guys help me setting up a wireless proxy server? I have asked a question similar situation as this before, but because i didn't know what was it really to ask but now i do. I want to limit the amount of bandwidth that users allow to use per day in my flat.

My flat has 13 people and all using internet that has bandwidth only 20GB/month. It usually runs out in about 2 or 3 days at most, then it will dropped down to dial up for the rest of the month.

Now i'm pretty sure you guys knows about free wireless at some Mcdonald's restaurant or other places. Their free wireless is not unlimited, all users need to login to their website to be able to use and it is limited at 50MB usually. Now i want to setup similar way as network at Mcdonald's where all users need to login before they can use internet and there's a limit for 50MB per day and that would be 650MB for 13 people and 19.5GB per month.

I'm just one of the users in the flat. I have asked my landlord and he said it's a good idea so he allowed me to do it but i have no idea where to start and what to do yet. My landlord said he just put a wireless modem downstairs and setup a password to prevent neighbours or other people around the house use it and that was it.

[Edit] By the way, i just want something simple, doesn't have to be fancy like network at Mcdonald's or other free public wifi.

So please guys, help me! I am really sick of using dial up everyday.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: by the way, this is generally referred to as 'Captive Portal' functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this kind of setup is not as simple as it seems like it ought to be (this is why most small businesses do it very badly). There's an open source package called [ChilliSpot](http://www.chillispot.info/) for this, but it will require

1. a compatible firmware running on your router
2. a RADIUS server set up (FreeRADIUS or equivalent running on a seperate PC)
3. A webserver configured to interact with the RADIUS server (could be on the same machine, they have example configurations)

Setup is a bit complicated, and you need a bit of hardware (since a computer is required to act as RADIUS and web server).

There are commercial solutions for this that are much easier to set up (Antamedia comes to mind), but they tend to be very expensive (several hundred US$).

Comment: I have googled Antamedia, it looks interesting. I've read through it, it seems like it needs 2 computers to be able to make this work. For example, i have to have 2 computer, one running the software (24/7) and another my personal computer which i can use (turn on or off anytime). I have only one laptop at the moment, would that work with this software?

Comment: In all systems I know of a computer running 24/7 is a necessity, because routers lack the capacity to handle authentication/accounting internally. Perhaps antamedia could advise you on a different configuration, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you go to http://coova.org/ and get necessary packages there. As another user said you might need radius if you are after more complicated setup.

Comment: Sorry, i am not after complicate setup or anything, i'm just looking for any easiest way to setup and work. @jcrawfordor suggested to use a software call "Antamedia" i've read through it, it seems like i need 2 computers to make this work. I have only one laptop. Is it going to work? by using his suggested software or you suggested website?